# Convert AAC bytes to WAV bytes in Python without ffmpeg?

Tags: python, wav, aac

I have audio bytes that are AAC encoded and would like to transcode them to a bytearray in Python in WAV format (PCM signed 16-bit little-endian) without calling ffmpeg to do so. How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I do that with soundfile library which is very light and portable.